# Change comma to dot for decimal place - Googlesheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have rows of numbers in the wrong format.
Current format is 1 000,00
needs changing to 1000.00               .  How can I change this format?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, just go to file -> configuration -> and select United States format. It takes . as the decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can adjust it here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/apbpC.png

If not, it may be your language settings in the browser / your computer that it's taking your default format from.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted (value) the numbers to a new spreadsheet, changed the language settings to Polish, applied format as currency, then copied and pasted (with format) to the original spreadsheet.

Comment: Has this solved your problem? If this is an update to your question, the question should be edited to include it.